# size inputs must be scalar

Tags: matlab

can someone please explain me how can I fix the error "size inputs must be scalar"? When I run the code in matlab it works correctly but when i run the compiled exe I obtain this error:

> Error using randperm
>
> Size inputs must be scalar.
>
> Error in randsample (line 162)
>
> Error in 'mycode' (line
>   .'indexesWith0=randsample(1:n-sumboo,nToAnalyze-sumboo); % '..)
>
> MATLAB:NonScalarInput

```
nToAnalyze=options.nToAnalyze;
if isempty(nToAnalyze) 
    Exclude='';
else
    if nToAnalyze >n
        error(['nToAnalyze must be smaller or equal than ' num2str(n)])
    end
    boo=double_y ==1; %  
    notboo=~boo; %  
    sumboo=sum(boo); %  
    seq=1:n;  %  

      indToExtractWith0=seq(notboo); % indexes of units which have 0
      indexesWith0=randsample(1:n-sumboo,nToAnalyze-sumboo); % 
      UnitsToAnalyzeWith0=indToExtractWith0(indexesWith0); %  
      UnitsToanalyze=[seq(boo) UnitsToAnalyzeWith0]; %  
      Exclude=setdiff(seq,UnitsToanalyze); %  
end
```

thank you

Comment: Can you check the values you provide to randsample

Comment: You give inputs to the fucntion, the ones that are supposd to be size, as scalars.

Comment: randsample(1:n-sumboo,nToAnalyze-sumboo);     "1:n-sumboo" is a double array (1x348392), while   nToAnalyze-sumboo  is a scalar (value =78887)  ... thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [MATLAB help](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/stats/randsample.html) there are two ways of using `randsample` with two input arguments:

> **y = randsample(n,k)** returns a k-by-1 vector y of values sampled
>   uniformly at random, without replacement, from the integers 1 to n.
>
> **y = randsample(population,k)** returns a vector of k values sampled
>   uniformly at random, without replacement, from the values in the
>   vector population. The orientation of y (row or column) is the same as
>   population.

So it's legal to supply a vector for the first argument, `n`, but not for the second one, `k`.

If you look inside the randsample function (type `edit randsample`) and go to line 162 you can see that the command that actually throws this error is

```
y = y(randperm(k));
```

where `k` is the second argument to `randsample`. So it looks as if somehow, when you run the compiled code, you're ending up with a value for `nToAnalyze-sumboo` that is a vector, not a scalar, and you just haven't replicated this case when you test your code in the editor.

This could happen if `options.nToAnalyze` is a vector; it could also happen if `double_y` is a matrix (dimension 2 or higher) as `boo` will then have the same dimension and `sum(boo)` will have one dimension less. Check the rest of your code to figure out where either of these could be happening.

Comment: I've compiled the code after it has been modified  "indexesWith0=randsample(n-sumboo,nToAnalyze-sumboo)" but I get the same error... thank you

Comment: OK, I checked the help for `randsample` more closely. See edit.

Comment: I solved the problem by introducing the line:  `if ~isnumeric(nToAnalyze)
        nToAnalyze=str2double(nToAnalyze);
    end`. thank you